# Add name value pairs to a JObject within a JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
{
    "x": null,
    "y": null,
    "z": null,
    "things": [
        {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 1
        },
        {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to push another pair into `things[0]` so that it reads

```
"things": [
{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 1,
    "z": 9000
},
```

I can easily modify the values like this:

```
JObject myobject = JObject.Parse(responseString);
JArray myarray = (JArray)myobject["things"];

myarray[0]["x"] = 9000;
```

I can't figure out how to add/append to this object instead. It appears `myarray[0]` is a `JToken`, even though it is an object when I do `GetType()`..

Comment: did you used myarray[0]["z"] = 9000;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cast the array item to a `JObject`, then use the `Add` method to add a new `JProperty`.  Like so:

```
JObject myobject = JObject.Parse(responseString);
JArray myarray = (JArray)myobject["things"];

JObject item = (JObject)myarray[0];
item.Add(new JProperty("z", 9000));

Console.WriteLine(myobject.ToString());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Cb5lu

Comment: Thank you Brian! :D
btw, why is this needed ? the array item reports as a LinQ.JObject Type even before I do the Cast (?)

Comment: `JToken` is the base class for `JObject`, `JArray`, `JValue`, etc.  The `Type` property is there so that you have a way to find out what type of `JToken` it is so that you can cast it appropriately if you need to.  `JToken` itself does not have an `Add` method, whereas `JObject` and `JArray` do, so you have to cast to the correct subclass to be able to call the method.  Make sense?

Comment: It makes perfect sense :) thanks again Brian for elaborating