# How to add object to JObject?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm creating my own `JObject` with different key-value pairs with the following code:

```
JObject obj = new JObject();
obj.Add(new JProperty("Key", "Value"));
```

But how do I add an Object to my `JObject`? For example:

```
ObjectName{
    "Key": "Value",
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2" 
}
```

Hope someone can help out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add name value pairs to a JObject within a JArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630795/add-name-value-pairs-to-a-jobject-within-a-jarray)

Comment: See also [Add JObject to JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48168738/215552)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Add method to add an object to your JObject. You can see more here:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Add.htm